# Angular service variable change and updated another component

Tags: javascript, angular

service.ts

```
clicked: string = '';
clickEvent(item){
      this.clicked = ( this.clicked.length > 0 && this.clicked == item ) ? '' : item;
  }
```

parent.component

```
 constructor(private qqs: qqService) {}
  clicked = this.qqs.clicked;
```

parent.html

```
<app-child [clicked]="clicked"></app-ou>
```

child.component

```
constructor(private qqs: qqService) {}
    @Input() clicked;
     click(item){
       this.qqs.clickEvent(item);
       }
```

child.html

```
<div class="a" (click)="click('some string')"></div>
```

If user click at child.html

child.component click() will work and pass some string to service

and service will change variable clicked

than parent. component get a new variable from service

and pass to all child by @Input()

Now my problem is a parent. component can't get a new variable from service

How to fix that?

Comment: Use rxjs Behavior Subject or Subject to share data between components.

Comment: In the child, you add an EventEmitter: `@Output() clickChanged = new EventEmitter<Item>();` and when the response returns, emit an event to the output `this.clickChanged.next(item)` or `this.clickChanged.emit(item)`.
In the parent: `<app-child (clickChanged)="myFuncForChange($event)"...`

Answer (score 0):

With reference to [Angular docs for component interacion](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

The `child component` exposes an `EventEmitter` property with which it `emits events` when something happens.

**The parent binds to that event property and reacts to those events.**

The child's `EventEmitter` property is an output property, typically adorned with an `@Output` decoration as seen in this `ParentComponent`

Here are the codes:

**parent.component**

```
constructor(private qqs: qqService) {}

onClicked(item) {
    console.log(item)
  }
```

**parent.html**

```
<app-child [clicked]="clicked"  (onclicked)="onClicked($event)"></app-ou>
```

**child.component**

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private qqs: qqService) {}
    @Input() clicked;

    @Output() onclicked = new EventEmitter<any>();

     click(item){
       this.clicked.emit(agreed);
    }
```

**child.html**

```
<div class="a" (click)="click('some string')"></div>
```

Comment: no mentions @user10892059, you can accept my answer if you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your code are following:

- Service: whenever `clickEvent` it changes reference of `clicked`.
- parent.component: you have saved reference of `qqs.clicked` in `clicked`(assuming `clicked` in your code refers to `this.clicked`), but whenever next time `clickEvent` will be called, the reference of `qqs.clicked` will be changed and inside parent `clicked` will have old reference.

Solution is either expose whole `qqs` to  template by making it public in *parent.component* and in *parent.html* replace `[clicked]="clicked"` to `[clicked]="qqs.clicked"`.

This will fix you problem, but i noted few more things:

- In your parent.html `<app-child [clicked]="clicked"></app-ou>` starting tag is not matching end tag.
- when you are already injecting Service in child too. what is need to pass value of `clicked` using property biding.

Comment: I try. But [clicked]="qqs.clicked" can't pass new variable to child.component. 
qqs.clicked can't get a variable

Comment: I can't understand the error, can you provide some more information.